# In france not getting result for Place API

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

I am using place API to serch Hospital, Doctors.
with types=pharmacy&keyword=pharmacy

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=50.468869,2.909696&radius=50000.0&types=pharmacy&keyword=pharmacy&language=&sensor=false&key=value

But not getting result in france ?
Is there any thing that we can improve in search API to get accurate result ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API behaviour is strange between category keywords and searched word. As you can see here, if you search for "pharmacy" in France you don't get the same results as if you search for "pharmacie" :

- https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=pharmacy&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D6&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&sa=N&tab=wl
- https://maps.google.fr/maps?q=pharmacie&sugexp=chrome,mod%3D6&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&sa=N&tab=wl

Notice that for the first one you can see "category : Pharmacy" on the left results list. And not for the other request.

Comment: No, the above url does not contain value for key.
To check you need to put key value against key parameter in above URL.

Comment: Thanks for quick response.

Actaully my app is live on google play store :
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matrix.emergency

But few clients from France and Germany are complaining about getting wrong results for doctor and dentist at there location.

It will be great if you can suggest me any changes that we can do in above API request to get more accurate results.

Comment: Ok I think I understand your problem. This is because you do a research about the word "pharmacy" that doesn't exist in french. What you are really looking for is a "pharmacie" and here, you will get much more results (and "real" and accurate results). Because if you search for "pharmacy" you only get places that are categorized in pharmacy type.
Try this (for Toulouse, France) : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=43.607245,1.443964&radius=50000.0&types=pharmacy&keyword=pharmacie&language=&sensor=false&key=theAPIKey

Comment: Thanks Grsmto !
But this is not specified in Google place API, keyword should be in place local language.
I am still confused that using this will make any difference.

Comment: Yes this is strange...I don't understand well how the places API works for this because when you search for "pharmacy" you've got the places that are categorized as pharmacy. But when you type "pharmacie" you've got every places that have the keyword in their name but they are also categorized as "pharmacy"...So why they don't appear for "pharmacy" ? I don't know...May be the API make a difference for places that are categorized by the owner of the place and places that "auto-categorized".